# How should a T-SQL script detect if it's running in Azure SQL Database or on-premise?

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Suppose I have a piece of T-SQL that gets variously run both on Azure SQL Database and on-premise SQL Server. How can I programmatically detect, *within the script itself*, which of these is the prevailing context?

I note that

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

on Azure SQL Database yields a string that starts

```
Microsoft SQL Azure
```

but parsing the output of `@@VERSION` doesn't make for a nice feeling, and of course the specifics could change at any time.

Is there a more-obviously-correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

Can also check it, when its not SQL Azure you know its on prem.